# Pressure inside a covered pot

Tags: thermodynamics

If I have a pot covered with a cover and assuming that and the pressure is the atmospheric pressure outside the pot.  Will I consider the pressure inside the pot also the atmospheric pressure which is 10325 Pa or not? Is this assumption valid? Or the height of the column of the air inside pot is much smaller than the column of air outside which mean that pressure outside is larger than pressure inside.?

Comment: If the pot does not deform then the pressure inside the pot could have any (reasonable) value,  Think of gas cylinders and vacuum flasks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You asked a similar question before.

[A perfectly fitting pot and its lid often stick after cooking](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/440322/a-perfectly-fitting-pot-and-its-lid-often-stick-after-cooking)

What the pressure is depends...

First the overall assumption is that you're cooking with water.

If the lid on the pot doesn't absolutely seal the pot, then the pressure in the headspace of the pot will just be the ambient atmospheric pressure. Some of that pressure will be due to the vapor pressure of water.

If the pot is a pressure cooker, then the pressure inside the pot will be greater than the ambient atmospheric pressure while hot, but a pressure cooker will leak air back into the pot as it cools.

If the pot is absolutely sealed then the pressure only depends on the temperature of the pot. Here since the pot is sealed the temperature could go over 100 C. In other words you could possibly convert all the water to steam inside the pot if the pot gets hot enough. (think bomb...)

Now your question in the other post asked about why the lid would "stick" to the pot. In that case the notion is that the lid acts as a one way valve. It lets pressure above ambient out, but then seals if the pressure inside the headspace is below ambient pressure. So as some of the water turns to vapor it sweeps some of the air out. In fact if the pot boils for an appreciable time the water vapor will sweep all the air out of the headspace. Then if the heat is turned off the vapor pressure of water drops and the pot lid seals. The vapor pressure of water is only about 2% of ambient at room temperature, so the headspace of the pot is nearly a vacuum. (As pointed out in the other post this is essentially what happens with canning lids...)